# jQuery - select all table rows after fourth

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to select all the rows of the table after the 4th one? I want to hide the remaining ones.

```
<table class="mytable">
<tr><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>

<tr><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`:gt()`](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selector:

```
$(".mytable tr:gt(3)").hide();​
```

Another option is to use [`slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) method:

```
$(".mytable tr").slice(4).hide();​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/F937n/

Comment: Isn't [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) just a native Javascript method (and the jQuery object uses it as native)?

Comment: @JaredFarrish Following [the sources](http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js) jQuery uses the native one.

Comment: Oh, you mean [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L21)? `;)`

Answer (score 1):

If you *always* want all rows after the 4th one hiding, then wouldn't standard CSS [`nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3anth-child) be cleaner, assuming your [browser supported it](http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child):

```
.mytable tr:nth-child(n+5) {
    display:none;
}​​​​​
```

Of course the jQuery equivalent would make it work on older browsers also:

```
$('.mytable tr:nth-child(n+5)​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​').hide();​​​​​
```